# I am in great pain working since 3hr to deploy the three.js code but some error is showing up

Tags: github, deployment, three.js, orbitcontrols

Please check my repo link : https://github.com/Rishav-k/Plane_Geology_WebGL
deployed link : https://rishav-k.github.io/Plane_Geology_WebGL/
Why i am getting error in hosting it on github /// someone please help me whats wrong with this code .
it would be helpful if you provide me the correct way to host three.js vite application without any error

I am expecting a proper way . I am getting mad i wasted 3hrs on this

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/354577)